# Update a Date field on the record in Flow Builder from the output of a formula date field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, formula-field, flow-builder

I am new to creating formulas in flows, and just starting to learn flows altogether.  I am trying to create a record-triggered flow to update an existing Date field on a record based off the output of a formula date field on the record.  The goal is to get the date field called **Expected Return** `ReturnDate__c`, to be the next following day after the value from the formula date field called **Return End Date** `ReturnEndDate__c`.

`ReturnEndDate__c` is calculated from 2 other fields (Number field **Requested Months** `RequestedMonths__c`) and (Date field called **Start Date** `StartDate__c`).

*Example*
Start Date: 6/1/2022
Requested Months: 2
Return End Date = 7/31/2022

I am trying to get the result **Expected Return: 8/1/2022**, which should be the next day after the Return End Date.  I have tried to creating a formula in the flow but I having trouble figuring out what functions to use to add days to the output for Return End Date field.  I have tried using `addDays`, it doesn't seem to work in flow.  Any advice on how I should try to approach this would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/376771/edit) your question to add one (or more) specific examples of formulas that you have tried, and how it is (or they are) not working (e.g., *exact* error text, unexpected result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have these fields set up in your object:

- **StartDate__c**: *as Date field*
- **RequestedMonths__c**: *as Number field*
- **ReturnEndDate__c**: *as Formula field (of type Date)*

To reach your **ReturnEndDate__c** you can use the following formula:

```
ADDMONTHS(StartDate__c, RequestedMonths__c)
```

Now you can create the field that will be filled by the record-triggered flow:

- **ReturnDate__c**: *as Date field*

#### Flow set up

In your flow create a formula to calculate the value of the **ReturnDate__c** field:
This will get your **ReturnEndDate__c** value and add 1 day.

> [image: Flow formula]

Then create a **Update record** action that will fill your **ReturnDate__c** field with the value of the formula:

> [image: Flow example]

> [image: Flow update record]

---

Your end result should look something like this:

> [image]

Hope it helps!